# Protocol Buffer data encoding

Tags: node.js, express, protocol-buffers

My app code looks like:

**main.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ProtoBuf = require("protobufjs");
let builder = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile("protos/player.proto")
let Main = builder.build("Main")
let Player = Main.PlayerInfo

app.get('/test1', function (req, res) {
  let plr = new Player("name", "123")
  let enc = plr.encode()
  res.send(`Message is: ${enc}`); // Response 'Message is: ByteBufferNB(offset=0,markedOffset=-1,limit=11,capacity=16)'

});
app.get('/test2', function (req, res) {
  let plr = new Player("name", "123")
  let enc = plr.encode()
  res.send(`Message is: ${enc.toBuffer()}`); // Response 'Message is: name123'

});
app.get('/test3', function (req, res) {
  let plr = new Player("name", "123")
  let enc = plr.encode()
  res.send(`Message is: ${plr.toBuffer()}`); // Response 'Message is: name123'

});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

**player.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

package Main;

message PlayerInfo {
  required string username = 1;
  required string password = 2; 
}
```

When i visit those pages, i get responses like:

```
/test1 - Message is: ByteBufferNB(offset=0,markedOffset=-1,limit=11,capacity=16)
/test2 - Message is: name123
/test3 - Message is: name123
```

**Question:**

Why in 2 and 3 example i see data as it is, not ecoded (despite the fact that I using encode() and toBuffer() functions)?

Comment: The encoded form of your message should be (I think): `\012\004name\022\003123` Is it possible that Buffer.toString() strips out `\012`, `\004`, `\022`, `\003` for display purposes? `\012` is `\n`, but the others have no printable form.

Answer (score 0):

On 3 you are usding `toBuffer` on `plr`, I guess you meant to do it on `enc`.

This should give you the encoded data:

```js
res.send(plr.encode().toBuffer(), (err, data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```